# disabled screen orientation hotkeys not released

Tags: hotkeys, intel-graphics, pycharm

The Intel graphics driver on my Lenovo laptop uses ctrl+alt+arrow keys to change the screen orientation. I was able to disable it from the tray icon menu easily enough ([and made sure the registry changed accordingly](https://superuser.com/q/358263/41093)).

PyCharm uses the same combination for navigating back\forwards, but the combination doesn't work for me in PyCharm. Is it correct to assume that the Intel driver is still capturing the key combination but just doesn't respond to it? How to I re-route the combination to PyCharm?