# Disable screen orientation hot keys in windows 8 (ctrl alt arrow)

Tags: windows, windows-8, hotkeys

I want to disable the screen orientation hot keys. I have tried looking in the NVIDIA control panel, but I have not found the option in there yet.

**Details:**

- I am using an Asus Zenbook running windows 8.
- My computer runs both the intelHD graphics that is integrated into the i7 proccessor and a NVIDIA 650m.

Comment: Other dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/279756/how-to-disable-the-screen-orientation-hotkeys-in-windows-xp

Comment: One option is to disable the `Intel(R) HD Graphics Control Panel Service` altogether. Or don't have it be started automatically.

See more info here: https://communities.intel.com/thread/51399?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The screen orientation keys are probably provided and controlled by the Intel HD driver (it's been a standard feature of Intel video drivers for years now).

Use the Intel HD utility to disable them:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, I thought the graphics would have been controlled by the NVIDIA control panel.

Comment: One can easily open this utility window through the hotkey Ctrl+Alt+F12

Comment: The Intel utility isn't listed in the start menu in my system. It was the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+F12 that bought it up!

Comment: I managed to disable all the shortcuts. But is there a way to only prevent the shortcuts for Ctrl + Alt + Left, Ctrl + Alt + Right, and Ctrl + Alt + Down? I don't really want to change them to something else obscure, but is that the only way? It won't let me set it blank.