# How to column select in Sublime Text 2 on a HP Envy laptop

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, intel-graphics, hp-envy

I want to be able to column select in Sublime Text 2 on my HP Envy laptop (p/n: J4Z51EA#UUW) using the keyboard shortcuts [Ctrl+Alt+Up or Ctrl+Alt+Down](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html). By default, these shortcuts were used by Intel HD driver but that could be [disabled using the Intel HD Utitity](https://superuser.com/questions/592684/disable-screen-orientation-hot-keys-in-windows-8-ctrl-alt-arrow).

But back in Sublime, nothing happens when I press Ctrl+Alt+Up or Ctrl+Alt+Down. I have tried restarting my computer but that does not change anything.

Comment: I have this same problem on an VAIO Sony Laptop. I have also disabled the default behavior of Ctrl+Alt+Up and Ctrl+Alt+Down, but no luck. Haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem, running Windows 8.1, using Sublime Text 3, on a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga.

The fix is to go into the Intel HD Driver Settings, and change the shortcuts to something else. Make sure that these shortcuts don't clobber anything else you might use (I chose Alt+Shift+0 and Alt-Shift+1). Then, you can still disable the shortcuts, and the Intel HD Driver will not interfere with Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down any more.

Comment: This works! I had forgotten that I posted this here. I actually opted for [another solution](https://communities.intel.com/message/272663#272663) just a few days ago that was a bit more drastic: to make the "Intel(R) HD Graphics Control Panel Service" service not automatic but manual. Apparently, the behavior is bug in the Intel driver.

Comment: That does seem a bit drastic! I hope that they fix it some day, but I suspect it's probably not going to be in an acceptable amount of time for any reasonable user.